# I sended a json format message made by javascript axios to python flask server on GCP. but rejected

Tags: json, flask, google-cloud-platform, promise, axios

[image]

Hello. I made a simple client-server program that runs on my local machine.

This is some information that I configured.

1. Client file using Axios uses 3001 port.
2. Python file using flask runs on 5000 ports.
3. when I executed server.py with `FLASK_APP=server.py FLASK_DEBUG=0 flask run`, It runs well. It shows proper JSON on my chrome.
4. In my local testing, the sendMessageToServer function sends JSON format file to the flask server, and the flask server returns well. There is no error.
5. So I tried to migrate these codes to the Google cloud platform to deploy my code. Flask file and javascript file have different ports.
6. First of all, the 3001 port project runs well. (client.js is a subset of large client chat program)
7. When I headed to call sendMessageToServer on client.js, it returns the last picture's Promise JSON. PromiseStatus = rejected, Network Error that I can't figure out. And POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED shows up.
8. When I click 127.0.0.1 on these two-place, They redirected to different addresses. The first place is client.js opened on cloud shell. Second place is google cloud terminal server log when I run server.py Only second way works well.

What's the solution to my situation?

```js
// client.js
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require ("axios");
const headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"     : "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "withCredentials" : "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"    : "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"    : "PUT, PATCH, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTION"
}

function sendMessageToServer(converstation ) {
  // console.log('before axios.post')
  var t = axios.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
    {
      conversation: 'hello axios and flask'
    },
    {
      headers: headers
    });
  return t
  // When I call sendMessageToServer, 'before and after' log message shows up on my broswer. and third screenshot comes 
  //between before and after log messages. 
  //Client.js and server.py are located on same server but have diffrent ports  
  // console.log('after axios.post')

}
```

```
#server.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import keras
import api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False
cors = CORS(app)
@app.route("/", methods =['POST'])
def model():
    result = {
            'model name': 'work',
            'api ver': '1.0',
            'predict result': '100' ,
    }
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

[image]
[image]
**UPDATED: I've just changed server.py port as 0.0.0.0:5000, but error messages didn't changed**

And port listens well
[image]

Comment: I'm not following the complete story but something that is in my mind is the notion that you appear to have a server listening on "127.0.0.1".  That can cause problems.  That may mean that incoming requests can ONLY arrive from the same machine on which the server is running.  You may want to consider specifying "0.0.0.0" as the IP address on which your app is listening.

Comment: Where the JS code is running? On your server or on your browser? The screenshot of your error is confusing

Comment: JS code runs on my client server, getting messages from user. And the message have to be sent to server.py.

Comment: seems like simmilar issue: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-can-i-call-api-port-from-react-app-using-ip-address-but-not-when-i-use-localhost